# Find min and max data from multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table that specifies exactly what date and time each employee was in a particular office.I want to know on what date and time each employee arrived at work and on what date and time he left work. I also want to know how many times he has been at work in each time process.

`EmployeeTable` looks like this:

| id | EmployeeID | DateP | TimeP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 1397/01/02 | 01:30 |
| 2 | 11111 | 1398/05/09 | 05:30 |
| 3 | 11111 | 1398/06/07 | 05:10 |
| 4 | 22222 | 1398/08/09 | 06:12 |
| 5 | 22222 | 1399/02/01 | 07:15 |
| 6 | 11111 | 1399/07/02 | 08:51 |
| 7 | 11111 | 1399/08/06 | 12:20 |
| 8 | 33333 | 1399/09/04 | 20:01 |
| 9 | 33333 | 1399/12/08 | 22:05 |
| 10 | 33333 | 1400/01/01 | 23:11 |
| 11 | 33333 | 1400/02/05 | 14:10 |
| 12 | 22222 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 |

I want exactly select Min and Max date and time for each Employee when present in a office and  how many times he/she has been present at work in each stage.:

| id | EmployeeID | MinDateP | TimeMinDateP | MaxDateP | TimeMaxDateP | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 1397/01/02 | 01:30 | 1398/06/07 | 05:10 | 3 |
| 2 | 22222 | 1398/08/09 | 06:12 | 1399/02/01 | 07:15 | 2 |
| 3 | 11111 | 1399/07/02 | 08:51 | 1399/08/06 | 12:20 | 2 |
| 4 | 33333 | 1399/09/04 | 20:01 | 1400/02/05 | 14:10 | 4 |
| 5 | 22222 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 | 1 |

This is the SQL code that indicates exactly when each employee arrived at work and when he or she left work :

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateP, TimeP) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY DateP, TimeP) rn2
    FROM 
        EmployeeTable
),
cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, rn1 - rn2
                           ORDER BY DateP, TimeP) rn_first,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, rn1 - rn2
                           ORDER BY DateP DESC, TimeP DESC) rn_last
    FROM 
        cte
)
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN DateP END) AS MinDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN TimeP END) AS TimeMinDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN DateP END) AS MaxDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN TimeP END ) AS TimeMaxDateP
FROM 
    cte2
GROUP BY
    EmployeeID,
    rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    MIN(DateP), MIN(TimeP);
```

But I want to know how many times each employee has been at work at any given time (`Count` column)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: FYI You could remove your 2nd CTE completely and simplify the whole thing if you created a `DATETIME` column that combined `DateP` and `TimeP` in the first CTE using `DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DateP), CAST(TimeP AS DATETIME2(7))) AS DateTimeP` - [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e4e5afe6f6f0be075ad8d3e8657c2d7d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to know the number of records in each employee island.  In that case, just select `COUNT(*)` in your final query:

```sql
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN DateP END) AS MinDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN TimeP END) AS TimeMinDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN DateP END) AS MaxDateP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN TimeP END) AS TimeMaxDateP,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM cte2
GROUP BY
    EmployeeID,
    rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    MIN(DateP),
    MIN(TimeP);
```